# Everyday statistics for CRM-like system

Tags: sql, database, bigdata, backend, crm

How should I organize database to keep statistics for each day about sales, leads, tasks if I need to filter this information by 10+ parameters.

For instance: I want to know how many leads had been sent to "sold" from 2018-01-01 to 2018-03-31 from those, which were created from 2017-10-01 to 2017-10-31 with custom_field1 set to 22, custom field2 set to 1, etc.

My first idea is to copy each lead every day to statistic at 23:59. I need advice if it's a bad idea, because now we have about 6k leads. And copying them each day is ridiculous.

Comment: 6k is not bigdata.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff each month +1k-2k leads. each day copying 6-10-20k leads * year - closer to bigdata. The question is how to organize it. Is my method usable in this situation? Or could I achive better performance in queries if I use replication. And if I could, is it better to keep it in one table or maybe I will have to create new table for each period of time, etc. Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Your data is small enough that you can just calculate the statistics using queries.  No reason to complicate the data model.

Comment: I had a case, where filtering statistics had 2 filters - date range and office. In this case I've stored count_leads, new_lead, archive_lead, count_new_leads, etc with office id every day. So I could sum each office to get statitstics for all offices or some of them. But now I have to filter them by 10+ rows. It means that I can set any combination of these filters. So the counters now is not good idea. The only solution I found is to make "instances" - copies of all records for each day so I can see how many leads were transfered to other status or pipeline, filter them by any row.

Comment: Just tell me if it'll work)